# how to pass servlet action in redirect function in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

in my first jsp i am poping up a jsp window. in this pop up window i am selecting few request and passing it to another jsp through servlet. my problem is while i am passing the request from pop up window to second jsp the second jsp is shown in the same pop up window only. how can i close the pop up window and pass the request to second jsp . in the following code i have used redirect function in pop up window but it is not working. please help me how to go about it....

```
function UpdatePannel()
{
var selectedIds;
var count=0;
for (i=0; i<document.frm1.check1.length; i++)
{
if (document.frm1.check1[i].checked==true)
{
if(count==0){
selectedIds=document.frm1.check1[i].value; 
count=count+1; 
}
else
selectedIds=selectedIds+","+document.frm1.check1[i].value;
}
}
alert(selectedIds);  

//document.frm1.action="<%=contextPath%>/AddInterviewPannel?ids="+selectedIds;
//window.close()
     //   document.frm1.submit();

     redirect();
} 

function redirect()
{
opener.location.href="<%=contextPath%>/AddInterviewPannel?ids="+selectedIds;
window.close()
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate its not working ?

Comment: i need to pass the following servlet action from the pop up window and close the window how can i do this                             <%=contextPath%>/AddInterviewPannel?ids="+selectedIds

Comment: Can you please check my answer below ?

Comment: ya i checked it u r calling another jsp file directly but i want to call a servlet action

Comment: then just URL would be different just mention servlet's URL

Comment: the context path contain the url and addinterviewpannel is servlet action and id is the value i am passing to the servlet i am getting Error 404--Not Found

Comment: can you tell me what URL exactly it is trying to access and giving you 404 ?

Comment: I don't see `AddInterviewPannel` here in this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this javascript in parent window. call this javascript function `redirect` in parent function with the parameter need to passed like `redirect(selectedIds)`

update the javascript function redirect to accept parameter

```
function redirect(selectedIds){
    opener.location.href="<%=contextPath%>/AddInterviewPannel?ids="+selectedIds;
    popupobj.close() // popupobj => have the reference to popup , initialize this with return value of window.open
}
```

Comment: how to give reference to popup and initialize with return value can u please elaborate on it . since i am learning jsp servlet now i have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: call the redirect(selectedIds) function using opener object like  opener.redirect(selectedIds) . This way you can pass the value to javascript in parent window.

Answer (score 1):

popup.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<a href="#" onclick="window.opener.location.href='new.htm';">change parent</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

parent.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('popup.html','kid','resizable=no,scrollbars=no,width=250,height=148,toolbar=no');">click</a> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Its working fine for me.. Compare your code and find out the reason.