# Popup window - perform the action and close

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I'm using popup window for code authentification, where are only following components:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.masterKey.code}" />
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.checkMaster}" value="OK" type="submit"/>
```

Button calls method checkMaster() which set the boolean variable true or false

```
public void checkMaster(){
  if (findMasterKey(masterKey.getCode())) Settings.ONCOST = true;
  else Settings.ONCOST = false;
}
```

But I would like to close popup window after perform the action (every time button is pressed).

But don't know how.. could you help me?

Update:

```
public static boolean findMasterKey(String key)
{
  Session session = DaoSF.getSessionFactory('R').openSession();
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MasterType.class);
  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("code", key));
  MasterType foundMT = (MasterType)criteria.uniqueResult();

  if (foundMT != null) return true;
  else return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After on action performed navigate this page to some page say `Foo`

on page load of `Foo` execute `windows.close()` javascript

Comment: Oh, thanks for quick reply. And could you tell me how? I'm not much experienced. Or isn´t there some more elegant solution say using onclick parameter of commandbutton? For example call checkMaster() method using javascript function and something like self.close()?

Comment: This one is more appropriate. consider that while performing your action some exception arise so user will never come to know about it. and in this case it should get handled properly

Comment: Aha, I understand now. Using faces-config.xml is actual xhtml redirected to the foo.xhtml, and there is closed using by <script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>. It really works! Thank you Jigar!

Comment: Just one more little thing :) page which I wanted redirect (1) is started from main page (2) and redirect to page foo.xhtml (3), how can I refresh main page(2) after closing foo page??

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816210/how-to-pass-servlet-action-in-redirect-function-in-javascript)

Comment: It (onclick="window.opener.location.href='bde.xhtml';") works too. Thank you again!

Comment: I've upvoted before :) So everything works, but one issue still remains - between form 1 and main form 2 is searching in database, so form 2 is well refreshed, but too early, object from database is not yet found and boolean value is not correctly calculated. OnClick method is too fast! :) Do you have some idea?

Comment: how do you load the data from DB ?

Comment: using hibernate (please see my original question, i've edited it)

Comment: It's hard to explain; but no problemo, your solutions are good for me, I'll only have to find some trick how to refresh main page at the right time :) thanks for your rich help!

Comment: You can initiate a new question. with explanation